# MS Access Generic Pass-Through Query to SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, ms-access, pass-through

I successfully set up a pass-through query in MS Access. It is generic in the sense that I can set the SQL on the fly via the DAO.QueryDef ".SQL" property.

Problem is, I cannot seem to set the ".ReturnsRecords" property on the fly. Whatever is in the query's Property Sheet seems to be stuck there.

An example might be helpful:

```
Dim qdef As DAO.QueryDef 
Set qdef = CurrentDb.QueryDefs(gPassThru)
qdef.ReturnsRecords = False  ' or True
qdef.SQL = "exec dbo.sp_whatever"
```

To reiterate,

1. qdef.SQL replaces whatever SQL was in the pass-through query
2. qdef.ReturnsRecords does not replace the property sheet definition of the pass-through

Is there any way of making the query completely generic, or do I need to create a separate queries based on whether records are returned?

Comment: Does it work any better if you do `Dim cdb As DAO.Database`, `Set cdb = CurrentDb`, `Set qdef = cdb.QueryDefs(gPassThru)`?

Comment: Is this saved query called by name elsewhere, or only executed immediately?  If only executed immediately, instead of having a saved query that you then change, just create a temporary QueryDef and set all necessary properties when needed.  You could create a function for the "boilerplate code".

Comment: Gord Thompson, that doesn't seem to help. I run into the same issue. Thanks.

C Perkins, a temporary query (that I have full control over) may be what I need. I will look into that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems to do the trick -- at least in the case where I don't need any records back. Thanks to C Perkins for steering me in this direction.

```
Dim strSQL As String
Dim qdef As DAO.QueryDef

Set qdef = CurrentDb.CreateQueryDef("") 'temporary pass-through
strSQL = "exec dbo.sp_whatever"

With qdef
  .Connect = gConnect
  .SQL = strSQL
  .ReturnsRecords = False
  .Execute
End With

Set qdef = Nothing
```